# Azure Devops - release pipeline with docker and Azure Container Registry (ACR) - problem with tag

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-container-registry

I have a very weird (and I suppose easy to fix) problem :) I am trying to have a working CI/CD pipeline in Azure. For this purpose, I have a repository in Azure devops and build and release pipeline created. I am publishing docker images to Azure Container Registry and during release, I am pulling this image (or at least - I am trying because it doesn't work) and I am trying to publish it on Webapp for containers. The "app" in my case it is SingalR hub on .NET Core 3.1 (but I don't suppose it makes a difference in the problem I am having)

If somebody wants to know in details how did i configure it - here is the tutorial i did use:

https://wikiazure.com/devops/azure-devops-automate-your-release-pipeline-to-provision-a-docker-container-to-azure-web-app-for-containers/

There were some doubts/differences in the tutorial (for example - why initially in the tutorial web app is being configured on Docker hub, when in fact it is using ACR. And why to connect to ACR the tutorial uses Azure Resource Manager connection (And not dedicated Docker container --> ACR connetion) And why later on in build pipeline there is some weird id set for dockerRegistryServiceConnection (i am giving in this place name of my ACR docker service connection)

But the whole build pipeline is working. It is publishing image to ACR. Everything is fine till this step.

The problem starts when I want to publish Azure WebApp with this image. The problem is with ... TAGS :) They are mismatching. I have automatic CI/CD - so when i push some change to the repo i see that release pipeline is working. It is creating the image in the ACR. Then i see, that release pipeline is running. Everything is "correct" - meaning no error are seen and the release is green.

But when i go to App service and Container settings i see from logs:

```
2020-04-21 18:02:28.321 INFO  - Pulling image: myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:c7aead0c46b66afc4131935efc7e6a51280dfb1a
2020-04-21 18:02:28.761 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:c7aead0c46b66afc4131935efc7e6a51280dfb1a not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown"}

2020-04-21 18:02:28.761 ERROR - Pulling docker image myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:c7aead0c46b66afc4131935efc7e6a51280dfb1a failed:
2020-04-21 18:02:28.762 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:c7aead0c46b66afc4131935efc7e6a51280dfb1a
2020-04-21 18:02:28.867 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://myAcrName.azurecr.io/v2/mobile/signalr/manifests/c7aead0c46b66afc4131935efc7e6a51280dfb1a: unauthorized: authentication required"}

2020-04-21 18:02:28.870 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
```

Very sophisticated error but the root cause is, that he is trying to get the image with non-existing tag, which is GIT COMMIT tag. And it suppose to get image by $(Build.BuildId) (this was my first attempt) or by $(Build.BuilNumber) (this was my second attempt)

Here is how this pipeline step (Deploy Azure App Service) looks like:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: mySubcsriptionARM
    appType: webAppContainer
    WebAppName: myProductsignalr
    DockerNamespace: myAcrName.azurecr.io
    DockerRepository: mobile/signalr
    DockerImageTag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

When i go to Release pipeline logs as a "Deploy Azure App Service" log i see that

```
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6012767Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6367124Z ==============================================================================
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6367787Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6368381Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6368765Z Version      : 4.163.5
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6369158Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6369603Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
2020-04-21T18:41:01.6369976Z ==============================================================================
2020-04-21T18:41:03.8970184Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'myProductsignalr'
2020-04-21T18:41:04.5534864Z Trying to update App Service Configuration settings. Data: {"appCommandLine":null,"linuxFxVersion":"DOCKER|myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:1f283100"}
2020-04-21T18:41:05.5465725Z Updated App Service Configuration settings.
2020-04-21T18:41:05.5495890Z Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME":"myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:1f283100"}
2020-04-21T18:41:06.2703349Z Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
2020-04-21T18:41:32.4715682Z Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
2020-04-21T18:41:33.4179962Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://myProductsignalr.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/111587494492765
2020-04-21T18:41:33.5945654Z App Service Application URL: http://myProductsignalr.azurewebsites.net
2020-04-21T18:41:33.6180118Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

[image]

What amazes me, that it is showing, that everything was ok - when it was far from "ok" :)

When i go to container settings after:
a) new code is published
b) build pipeline fires
c) release pipeline fires

i see it like this:

[image]

The tag is empty. If i would pick some tag manually:

[image]

And would choose: "SAVE" everything works correctly (SingalR is up and running correctly)

Clearly, I am missing something :/ Help me to see what;)

The root cause for me is that this fragment:
`DockerImageTag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'`
should insert build number (as stated) and the info from container settings should be:
`Pulling image: myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:20200421.09` (for BuildNumber 20200421.09) and it is inserting GIT COMMIT there as a tag and ends up with: `Pulling image: myAcrName.azurecr.io/mobile/signalr:c7aead0c46b66afc4131935efc7e6a51280dfb1a` Why o why?:)

**[UPDATE 22.04 10:56]**

I am posting build pipeline that i am using currently. I don't suppose it is important as it is working correctly, and the problem is more with deployment of correctly created docker image (on ACR), than with creating this image by the build pipeline. Nevertheless, here is the pipeline:

```
# Docker
# Build a Docker image 
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'MyProductDockerACR'
  imageRepository: 'mobile/signalr'
  containerRegistry: 'myAcrName.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push image to container registry
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        repository:  $(imageRepository)
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the release you are using is configured by `UI`. Its work logic much different with the one which configured by `YAML`.

In fact, here what you received just be the different performance produced while the running reason of the release are different.

I guess this release has the artifact source which targeting to **Repos**, right? You can confirm by checking its icon.

[image]

While the release source is coming from Repos, then the `Build.BuildNumber` would be the short part of the `commit id`(8 characters). And the `Build.BuildId` is the complete commit id.

If you want the release keep using the `Build.BuildNumber` value which the corresponding build (*created/pushed image*) was using, you must make sure the release source is targeting to this build. Also, this build need has artifacts generated. According to the YAML you shared, obviously, you haven't done that.

**Only** the release triggered by build along with artifact, then the `Build.BuildNumber` can be like `20200422.1` which the build was using.

So, please go your release definition, and re-configure its source to make sure it is coming from **build artifact** instead of repository.

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks. I forgot to mention this step as well as one of the point that keeps me wondering with this guide (https://wikiazure.com/devops/azure-devops-automate-your-release-pipeline-to-provision-a-docker-container-to-azure-web-app-for-containers/) because there was this information to use Azure Repository. I must contact the author regarding this - as it simply cannot work :)

Once again - thanks!

Comment: Is there more things like this? Is there any documentation about this? I checked predefined variables for releases and this is not written there.

Comment: If you set the "Default version" in the Release > Artifact section to "Specify at the time of release creation" (Where Artifact = ACR)

How can you refer to this in the Deploy task?

Is there any env variable you can use? I guess having :latest is a bad idea in production - if you build a new release that's not meant to go into prod, and it has the "latest" tag, you never really know when the App Service might reboot, and then pull the image.

Most docs I´ve seen always use "latest", which I assume is not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right. You have mismatch in tags.

In `Docker@2` task you can define tags:

```yaml
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to ACR
  inputs:
    command: login
    containerRegistry: devopsmanual-acr

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push
  inputs:
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: buildAndPush
    Dockerfile: build-docker-image/SampleAppForDocker/DOCKERFILE
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildNumber)

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Logout of ACR
  inputs:
    command: logout
    containerRegistry: devopsmanual-acr
```

Your definition should be pretty much like this one. Whre `devopsmanual-acr` is connection to your ACR.

[image: ACR connection definition].

I recently mad [a blog post](http://thecodemanual.pl/2020/04/20/how-to-build-docker-image-on-azure-devops.html) about creating docker images on Azure DevOps so maybe this will be also helpful for you.

If this won't be enough to solve your issue, please edit your question and show how you create and push your images.

Comment: But how is that helping with deploying the image on Azure Web Service?:) As i stated at the begining, the image is CORRECTLY published to Azure Container Registry (and from what i understand you did send me this part as build pipeline) But as i said, it is already working.
What is not working, is deploying this image on Webapp.

To remove any confusion, i will update my post with my current build pipeline YAML, but i don't suppose it is important as the problem is with deployment with correct images, not with creating the image itself.